# Connecting WCF Service from Device

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Is it possible to talk to WCF Service (tcpbinding) from external device? The device will basically write data on a port which WCF Service has to read and respond. Some of the references says only WCF client can talk to WCF Service.

Comment: Can you post some of those references, so we can validate it?

Comment: Please walk through this URL http://forums.asp.net/t/1594434.aspx?Can+a+WCF+service+listen+to+TCP+port+